# Changing form button style without losing 3d effect

Tags: html, css, button, browser

In Firefox and Internet Explorer, disabled buttons look greyed out and unclickable. But Chrome renders them just the same as enabled buttons.

[image: Firefox vs Chrome Buttons]

**How can I change the style of a button (for example its color) *without losing the 3d effect*, in order to make it look disabled?**

I am not asking how to make my own CSS button that looks the same in all browsers. I want to use the browser default buttons, but add an additional style to disabled buttons for those browsers that do not have a different style for them.

So far, everything I tried, like for example changing the background color or background image, made the button lose the 3d effect. The result looks like this, which is not what I want:

[image: Firefox button with transparent background image]

This is the result in Firefox, but it looks similar in the other browsers. The button looks much different from the default one.

Comment: You want to do like this :- http://cssdeck.com/labs/purely-css ?

Comment: No, this is what I want to avoid if possible. I want to change the look the __default__ button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add some transparency to the disabled buttons.

```css
button {
  padding: 10px;
}
button:disabled {
  opacity: 0.6;
}
```

```html
<button>button</button>
<button disabled>button disabled</button>
```

Comment: That's it! Works in all 3 browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using background gradients

https://jsfiddle.net/ammfoh3j/

There is a really useful site you can use to generate whatever kind of 3D looking effect you would like

http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

```
<style>
    button {
           margin:0px; padding:0px;
           background: #e4f5fc;
           background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #e4f5fc 0%,#bfe8f9 50%,#9fd8ef 51%,#2ab0ed 100%);
    }
</style>

<button>anything</button>
```

More accurate/pretty http://jsfiddle.net/j3Lgs3x5/2/

Comment: This is another example of a __CSS button__. I want to use the browsers' __default buttons__ and just change the look of the disabled buttons. While I know how to access a disabled button with CSS, I want to keep the default look and just change the color or other attributes.